# remove non-ascii characters and append a space in the field where the non-ascii characters were using a Perl all remove the double "quote"?

Tags: perl

I am passing a fixed (flat file). I need help to remove non-ascii characters and append a space in the field where the non-ascii characters were using a Perl all remove the double "quote"? I also need to remove any non visible characters and leave data:
I need to do this using regex;

Please see example below:

```
FOÃ¬O BAR       PO BOX 1234          
LASDÃ¬BA"       PO BOX 1234
VÃ¬D"Sxxx       PO BOX 1234

1: $str =~ s/"/ /g; removes the " and replaces it with a space (good)

2: $str =~ s/[^!-~\s]/ /g;
```

Please help: j

Comment: are you sure you meant remove all non-ascii characters and not remove all punctuation and whitespace? Because `my $str = "FOÃ¬O BAR"; print $str =~ s/[[:ascii:]]/ /gr;` outputs `"  Ã¬     "`. Which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I need punctuation other than quotation make (“double quotes”).  The double quotes are causing a problem in PL/SQL ("ORA-00911: invalid character") when I try to load the data in Data using PL/SQL: The non-ascii are just a nuisance and need the data to look clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
while(<DATA>)
{
    $_=~s/([^[:ascii:]]|")/ /g;
    print $_;
}


__DATA__
FOÃ¬O BAR       PO BOX 1234
LASDÃ¬BA"       PO BOX 1234
VÃ¬D"Sxxx       PO BOX 1234
```

Output:

```
FO  O BAR       PO BOX 1234
LASD  BA        PO BOX 1234
V  D Sxxx       PO BOX 1234
```

Comment: This also worked; thanks. I had solved it with 2: $str =~ s/[^!-~\s]/ /g;

Answer (score 0):

I believe this replaces all special and invisible characters with spaces.

```
$str =~ s/(.)/(ord($1) > 127) ? " " : $1/egs;
```

Comment: my 2: $str =~ s/[^!-~\s]/ /g;  works to get rid of non ascii.  The problem I have is to also remove the double quotes on the string: For instance LASDÃ¬BA", becomes: LASD  BA" but I need it to be LASD  BA

Comment: 2: $str =~ s/[^!-~\s]| "/  /g;   Worked and output was what I needed.               LASDÃ¬BA" =  LASD BA  ;